# SignalR over three applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, signalr

We have three .Net Core applications, a Blazor Server front-end (A) that calls a web application (B) that calls another web application (C).

Applications A & C used to communicate via SignalR Core. We have had to put Application B in the middle of these (business reasons).

I would like to know if we can still have this communication via Application B?

Can we use B as a SignalR proxy - if so, how?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can have App B as a SignalR client and server at the same time. App B connects to App A, and subscribes to messages, and relay them to clients connected from App C.

Comment: Hi Sherif, I was thinking along these lines - can you demonstrate how to relay messages between client and server on the same system? - I'm very new to SignalR.

Comment: Client App(s) connecting to same hub server could communicate with each other. To get started with [SignalR Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [SignalR JavaScript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1) first, then integrate SignalR into your app(s).

Comment: I once made a proxy server for signalR 1 where I injected a custom `IHubManager`. I was able to hook in on `GetHubMethod` and capture calls. If I get time I can try and dig that up and rewrite it for .net Core.

Comment: @Jason, that would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to a [Hosted Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that runs in the background and holds a signalr client connection object to AppA.

```
public class SignalRClientService : IHostedService
{
    private HubConnection _connection;
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _myhubContext;

    public SignalRClientService(IHubContext<MyHub> myhubContext)
    {
        _myhubContext = myhubContext;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://example.com/hub")
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();
        await _connection.StartAsync();

        _connection.On<string, int>("myEvent", MyEventHandler);
    }

    // Route a message from C to A
    public Task Method1(string arg1, int arg2)
    {
        return _connection.SendAsync("Method1", arg1, arg2);
    }

    // Route a message from A to C
    private Task MyEventHandler(string arg1, int arg2)
    {
        return _myhubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("myEvent", arg1, arg2);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _connection.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

Your hub can look like

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly SignalRClientService _signalRClientService;

    public MyHub(SignalRClientService signalRClientService)
    {
        _signalRClientService = signalRClientService;
    }

    public Task Method1(string args1, int args2)
    {
        return _signalRClientService.Method1(args1, args2);
    }
}
```

There is a caveat here, is that since only one connection is maintained between A and B, A will basically see a single user. You can forward authentication tokens and maintain multiple connections between A and B but the solution will be a bit more complicated, but it is possible.

Comment: Hi Sherif. Thanks for that. I'll give it a try tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: I've had a bit of a play with this but I'm not getting anywhere. I clarify my question a bit. It is only one-way communication with this (C -> B -> A). Could you offer any more info on how to wire this up? C is an Api that passes objects back in the chain (C B A) only.

Comment: Finally sorted this. App B (the hosted service) wouldn't allow connections until I'd registered the SignalRClientService as a Hosted service and a scoped service. Weird. Thanks to @Sherif.